# How to auto rename multiple files with different indexing in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

how do i auto rename multiple files that are being copied with different indexing? i mean the `(0)`, `(1)`, etc... i.e. if i have two files in `Folder1` that has `a.txt` and `b.txt`, And another two same files inside the `Folder2` And copy the `a.txt` and `b.txt` from `Folder1` to `Folder2` then the `a.txt` will become `a(1).txt` and the `b.txt` to `b(1).txt`. how do i do it in a single instance? what came to my mind is to have many `Strings` and `Integers` as many as the files, but i will be dealing thousands of files. This is what i have so far.

```
Dim ii as Integer = 0
Dim iii as Integer = 0

Sub Copy()
   For i = 0 To updatedFiles.Count - 1
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(updatedFiles(i))
    Dim filePath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(updatedFiles(i))
    Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(updatedFiles(i))
    Dim newFile As String = filePath & "\" & fileName & "(" & ii & ")" & fileExt
    Dim newFile2 As String = filePath & "\" & fileName & "(" & iii & ")" & fileExt

    If File.Exists(Path.Combine(dest, updatedFiles(i))) Then
       ii += 1
       'Copy newFile
    ElseIf File.Exists(Path.Combine(dest, newFile)) Then
       iii += 1
       'Copy newFile2
    End If
   Next
End Sub
```

This doesn't do it right, from the situation above, the `a.txt` becomes `a(1).txt` but the `b.txt` becomes `b(2).txt`. the result should be

```
a (1).txt
b (1).txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have: Imports System.IO

When Copy() is run, all of the files from the source folder will be copied over to the destination folder, and renamed file(1).ext, file(2).ext, etc. if the file already exists in the destination folder:

```
Dim sourceFolder As String = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Folder1"
Dim destFolder As String = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Folder2"

Sub Copy()
Dim allFiles() As String  'Put all files in an array
allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder)
Dim i As Integer = 0   'File counter
Dim fileName As String = ""    'This will be name of file without path
Dim fileNameNoExt As String = ""    'Name of file without extension
Dim fileExt As String = ""          'File Extension

For j As Integer = 0 To allFiles.Count - 1
    i = 1  're-initialize i

    fileName = allFiles(j).Substring(allFiles(j).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    fileNameNoExt = allFiles(j).Substring(allFiles(j).LastIndexOf("\"), allFiles(i).LastIndexOf(".") - allFiles(j).LastIndexOf("\"))
    fileExt = allFiles(j).Substring(allFiles(j).LastIndexOf(".") + 1)

    If File.Exists(destFolder & "\" & fileName) Then
        While File.Exists(destFolder & "\" & fileNameNoExt & "(" & i & ")." & fileExt)
            i += 1
            'when while fails, i will hold the next value for file
        End While
        File.Copy(allFiles(j), destFolder & "\" & fileNameNoExt & "(" & i & ")." & fileExt)
    Else
        File.Copy(allFiles(j), destFolder & "\" & fileName)
        'if there is no file with the same name, there is a direct copy of the file to the destination folder
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is iterate twice. Once to add something to the name like `aTBR.txt,` `bTBR.txt`. TBR(To be renamed). You can put anything.
Second time to change name to what you would like it to be.

Harder way but maybe faster is to start with renaming last object. `d.txt` to `e.txt`?? then `c.txt` to `d.txt`, `b.txt` to `c.txt`
For that option you would need to keep their names in order in some `array`, or have them in alphabetic order and store their names `array` when you load app.

Update:

```
put Dim ii as Integer = 0
Dim iii as Integer = 0
```

inside for loop

Comment: can you share some sample code please? i don't have an idea how to do that.

Comment: but which one? and you create a new txt each time you start renaming?

Comment: please see my updated description, sorry for misinforming.

Comment: Ok. to get this right you want to copy files with same names from one folder to another. You want them to have " (1)"?

Comment: yes both of them, because they are different files so the index should not increment on the other file.

Comment: It is little confusing because you are not changing folder in your code.

Comment: Yes because i'm checking only for files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106915/discussion-between-claudius-and-dhan).